# Removing trailing pipe delimiter and pipe in between

Tags: sql, teradata

I am loading three phone numbers separated by pipe delimiter to a column in Teradata DWH.

1. If all three phone numbers are present for a row, value should
   look like this 123 | 456 | 789.
2. If first and the third are present then 123 | 789
3. If first and second are present than 123 | 456
4. If second and third are present then 456 | 789.

The query that is written is having some issues and if any of the phone numbers are missing say if the second phone number is missing it is storing values like this `123 | | 789` or if the third phone number is missing it is giving `123 | 456 |`.

We do not want trailing pipe or 2 pipes in between. Please suggest a Teradata query to implement this.

Comment: Share the query you have implemented so far so suggestions may be made on where you did wrong or what can be improved.

Comment: What is 'missing'? NULL? empty string?

Comment: May we see a query attempt from yourself, Sudarshan? We encourage posters to give their problem a genuine try before posting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The logic is:

*Assign different weights to each column and then evaluate weighted sum of length of all 3 columns. Assuming each phone number is 10 digits long. Here is the query/pseudocode*.

Query:

```
Select
case 1*LENGTH(firstCol)+2*LENGTH(secondCol)+4*LENGTH(thirdCol)
when 70 then CONCAT( firstcol,'|', secondcol,'|', thirdCol)  
when 60 then CONCAT( secondcol, '|', thirdCol)
when 50 then CONCAT( firstcol, '|', thirdCol)
when 30 then CONCAT (firstcol, '|', secondcol)
when 10 then firstcol
when 20 then secondcol
when 40 then thirdCol
else null
end
from phoneNumbersTable
```

Comment: Why are both question and answer downvoted? Looks like a valid question and Is there anything wrong with the logic?

Comment: If people do not specify why they have downvoted we can only guess. My guesses would be that the question was zero-effort, and it looks like is deserved its downvote. Your answer requested upvotes, so that may be reason for your score - we discourage requests for votes here.